# Improve performance when comparing two integer arrays of different lengths

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I have a bottleneck (or at least an area I think I can do better) with this comparer, which is basically an ordinal string comparer, but works against integer (ushort, though I don't think this matters) arrays.

The arrays can be different lengths, but the length would only matter if the elements [0..n] where n is the length of the shortest array match. In that case, the longer array is considered "greater."

1 2 3     <    1 2 4

1 2 3 5   <    1 2 4

1 2 5 3   >    1 2 4

1 2 3 4   >    1 2 3

```
    public int Compare(ushort[] x, ushort[] y)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
        while (pos < len && x[pos] == y[pos])
            pos++;

        return pos < len ?
            x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
            x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);

    }
```

Any ideas on how this could be optimized?

**Update**

In response to a commenter about what I'm actually doing here: I realize I had asked a question a long time ago related to this, which shows exactly what I am doing in context. The only major difference is that I am now using an array of `ushort` instead of a string for the keys since its a lot more compact.

Using the whole path as a key lets me use partial keys to obtain views from the sorted set which gives high performance for subset queries. I am trying to improve performance when building the index.  [Data structure for indexed searches of subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655431/data-structure-for-indexed-searches-of-subsets)

By the way I am extraordinarily impressed with the responses here so far, I've asked a lot of questions on SO over the years but this is far and away the most thoughtful and interesting collection of answers I've ever seen. I am not sure yet what the right answer is to my specific problem (which is -- millions of comparisons of short arrays) but every one of them has taught me something I didn't know.

Comment: you could probably skip `Math.Min`: `int len = x.Length > y.Length ? y.Length : x.Length;`

Comment: Are you doing a lots of comparisons of small arrays or are you doing a few comparisons of very large arrays ?

Comment: You can't go much better if you have to walk arrays... Can you represent your data as something else (i.e. similar to [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_trie) ) so comparisons of identical parts don't require walking all elements?

Comment: I am doing lots of comparisons of relatively small arrays. These arrays represent the path to a node in an HTML document; the number of elements is the depth of a node, so it's not especially likely it will be more than 30 or 40 for the most part. I am using a `SortedSet` where this is the key, so I couldn't easily change the data structure without major impact elsewhere.

Comment: @Romoku haven't tried all the suggestions yet but so far your comment has made the biggest difference :-/ .. I also got rid of `CompareTo` in the `return` and coded that out longform which helps as well. Sometimes it's the most obvious things..

Comment: @jamietre Generally when you want performance you need more control. You should profile the code and see which lines are taking the most resources with your worst/best/expected load and refactor the algorithm around those cases. If most of your arrays are small then you can unroll the loop. If you expect the arrays to have the same length then you can optimize for that. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: @jamietre just a stupid question: why do you need to sort arrays? in HTML document you already have them sorted by path - why do you need to sort them then?

Comment: Actually I forgot that I had asked a question a long time ago related to this, this shows exactly what I am doing, except I am now using an array of `ushort` instead of a string for the keys since its a lot more compact. Using the whole path as a key lets me use partial keys to obtain views from the sorted set which gives high performance for subset queries. I am trying to improve performance when building the index.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655431/data-structure-for-indexed-searches-of-subsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with, I tested up to around 16 mil (2^24), using a combination of your code and some parallel code.

```
public int CompareParallel(ushort[]x, ushort[] y, int len, int segLen)
{
    int compareArrLen = ( len / segLen ) + 1;
    int [ ] compareArr = new int [ compareArrLen ];
    Parallel.For ( 0 , compareArrLen , 
                   new Action<int , ParallelLoopState> ( ( i , state ) =>
    {
        if ( state.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue 
                 && state.LowestBreakIteration.Value < i )
            return;
        int segEnd = ( i + 1 ) * segLen;
        int k = len < segEnd ? len : segEnd;
        for ( int j = i * segLen ; j < k ; j++ )
            if ( x [ j ] != y [ j ] )
            {
                compareArr [ i ] = ( x [ j ].CompareTo ( y [ j ] ) );
                state.Break ( );
                return;
            }
    } ) );
    int r = compareArrLen - 1;
    while ( r >= 0 )
    {
        if ( compareArr [ r ] != 0 )
            return compareArr [ r ];
        r--;
    }
    return x.Length.CompareTo ( y.Length );
}

public int CompareSequential ( ushort [ ] x , ushort [ ] y, int len )
{
    int pos = 0;
    while ( pos < len && x [ pos ] == y [ pos ] )
        pos++;

    return pos < len ?
        x [ pos ].CompareTo ( y [ pos ] ) :
        x.Length.CompareTo ( y.Length );

}

public int Compare( ushort [ ] x , ushort [ ] y ) 
{
    //determined through testing to be the best on my machine
    const int cutOff = 4096;
    int len = x.Length < y.Length ? x.Length : y.Length;
    //check if len is above a specific threshold 
    //and if first and a number in the middle are equal
    //chose equal because we know that there is a chance that more
    //then 50% of the list is equal, which would make the overhead
    //worth the effort
    if ( len > cutOff && x [ len - 1 ] == y [ len - 1 ] 
           && x [ len/2 ] == y [ len/2 ] )
    {
        //segment length was determined to be best through testing
        //at around 8% of the size of the array seemed to have the
        //on my machine
        return CompareParallel ( x , y , len , (len / 100)*8 );
    }
    return CompareSequential ( x , y, len );
}
```

Here is the test I wrote:

```
class Program
{
    [Flags]
    private enum InfoLevel:byte
    {
        Detail=0x01, Summary=0x02
    }

    private static InfoLevel logLevel = InfoLevel.Summary;

    private static void LogDetail ( string content ) 
    {
        LogInfo ( InfoLevel.Detail,content );
    }

    private static void LogSummary ( string content ) 
    {
        LogInfo ( InfoLevel.Summary , content );
    }

    private static void LogInfo ( InfoLevel level , string content ) 
    {
        if ( ( level & logLevel ) == level )
            Console.WriteLine ( content );
    }

    private static void LogInfo ( InfoLevel level , string format, 
                                  params object[] arg )
    {
        if ( ( level & logLevel ) == level )
            Console.WriteLine ( format:format, arg:arg  );
    }

    private static void LogDetail ( string format , params object [ ] arg )
    {
        LogInfo ( InfoLevel.Detail , format, arg );
    }

    private static void LogSummary ( string format , params object [ ] arg )
    {
        LogInfo ( InfoLevel.Summary , format, arg );
    }

    const string _randTestResultHeader = "\r\nRandom Array Content\r\n";
    const string _equalArrayResultHeader = "Only Length Different\r\n\r\n";
    const string _summaryTestResultsHeader = 
                                "Size\t\tOrig Elps\tPara Elps\tComp Elps\r\n";
    const string _summaryBodyContent = 
                         "{0}\t\t{1:0.0000}\t\t{2:0.0000}\t\t{3:0.00000}\r\n";

    static void Main ( string [ ] args )
    {
        Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(File.Create("out.txt")));

        int segLen = 0;
        int segPercent = 7;
        Console.WriteLine ( "Algorithm Test, Time results in milliseconds" );
        for ( ; segPercent < 13; segPercent ++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( 
                      "Test Run with parallel Dynamic segment size at {0}%"
                       +" of Array Size (Comp always at 8%)\r\n" , segPercent);

            StringBuilder _aggrRandResults = new StringBuilder ( );
            StringBuilder _aggrEqualResults = new StringBuilder ( );

            _aggrRandResults.Append ( _randTestResultHeader );
            _aggrEqualResults.Append ( _equalArrayResultHeader );

            _aggrEqualResults.Append ( _summaryTestResultsHeader );
            _aggrRandResults.Append ( _summaryTestResultsHeader );


            for ( int i = 10 ; i < 25 ; i++ )
            {
                int baseLen = ( int ) Math.Pow ( 2 , i );
                segLen = ( baseLen / 100 ) * segPercent;

                var testName = "Equal Length ";
                var equalTestAverage = RandomRunTest ( testName , baseLen , 
                                                       baseLen, segLen );
                testName = "Left Side Larger";
                var lslargerTestAverage=RandomRunTest(testName,baseLen+10, 
                                                      baseLen, segLen );
                testName = "Right Side Larger";
                var rslargerTestAverage = RandomRunTest ( testName , baseLen ,
                                                        baseLen + 10, segLen );

                double [ ] completelyRandomTestAvg = new double [ 3 ];
                for ( int l = 0 ; l < completelyRandomTestAvg.Length ; l++ )
                    completelyRandomTestAvg [ l ] = ( equalTestAverage [ l ] +
                                                 lslargerTestAverage [ l ] +
                                              rslargerTestAverage [ l ] ) / 3;

                LogDetail ( "\r\nRandom Test Results:" );
                LogDetail ("Original Composite Test Average: {0}" ,
                           completelyRandomTestAvg [ 0 ] );
                LogDetail ( "Parallel Composite Test Average: {0}" ,
                            completelyRandomTestAvg [ 1 ]  );

                _aggrRandResults.AppendFormat ( _summaryBodyContent , 
                    baseLen , 
                    completelyRandomTestAvg [ 0 ] , 
                    completelyRandomTestAvg [ 1 ] , 
                    completelyRandomTestAvg [ 2 ]);

                testName = "Equal Len And Values";
                var equalEqualTest = EqualTill ( testName , baseLen , 
                                                 baseLen, segLen );

                testName = "LHS Larger";
                var equalLHSLargerTest = EqualTill ( testName , baseLen + 10 , 
                                                     baseLen, segLen );

                testName = "RHS Larger";
                var equalRHSLargerTest = EqualTill ( testName , baseLen , 
                                                     baseLen + 10, segLen );

                double [ ] mostlyEqualTestAvg = new double [ 3 ];
                for ( int l = 0 ; l < mostlyEqualTestAvg.Length ; l++ )
                    mostlyEqualTestAvg [ l ] = ( ( equalEqualTest [ l ] +
                                            equalLHSLargerTest [ l ] +
                                            equalRHSLargerTest [ l ] ) / 3 );

                LogDetail( "\r\nLength Different Test Results" );
                LogDetail( "Original Composite Test Average: {0}" , 
                           mostlyEqualTestAvg [ 0 ] );
                LogDetail( "Parallel Composite Test Average: {0}" , 
                            mostlyEqualTestAvg [ 1 ] );

                _aggrEqualResults.AppendFormat ( _summaryBodyContent , 
                                                 baseLen , 
                                                 mostlyEqualTestAvg [ 0 ] , 
                                                 mostlyEqualTestAvg [ 1 ] ,
                                                 mostlyEqualTestAvg [ 2 ]);
            }

            LogSummary ( _aggrRandResults.ToString() + "\r\n");
            LogSummary ( _aggrEqualResults.ToString()+ "\r\n");

        }
        Console.Out.Flush ( );
    }


    private const string _testBody = 
                  "\r\n\tOriginal:: Result:{0}, Elapsed:{1}"
                 +"\r\n\tParallel:: Result:{2}, Elapsed:{3}"
                 +"\r\n\tComposite:: Result:{4}, Elapsed:{5}";
    private const string _testHeader = 
                  "\r\nTesting {0}, Array Lengths: {1}, {2}";
    public static double[] RandomRunTest(string testName, int shortArr1Len, 
                                         int shortArr2Len, int parallelSegLen)
    {

        var shortArr1 = new ushort [ shortArr1Len ];
        var shortArr2 = new ushort [ shortArr2Len ];
        double [ ] avgTimes = new double [ 3 ];

        LogDetail ( _testHeader , testName , shortArr1Len , shortArr2Len ) ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            int arrlen1 = shortArr1.Length , arrlen2 = shortArr2.Length;

            double[] currResults = new double [ 3 ];

            FillCompareArray ( shortArr1 , shortArr1.Length );
            FillCompareArray ( shortArr2 , shortArr2.Length );

            var sw = new Stopwatch ( );

            //Force Garbage Collection 
            //to avoid having it effect 
            //the test results this way 
            //test 2 may have to garbage 
            //collect due to running second
            GC.Collect ( );
            sw.Start ( );
            int origResult = Compare ( shortArr1 , shortArr2 );
            sw.Stop ( );
            currResults[0] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset ( );

            GC.Collect ( );
            sw.Start ( );
            int parallelResult = CompareParallelOnly ( shortArr1 , shortArr2, 
                                                       parallelSegLen );
            sw.Stop ( );
            currResults [ 1 ] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset ( );

            GC.Collect ( );
            sw.Start ( );
            int compositeResults = CompareComposite ( shortArr1 , shortArr2 );
            sw.Stop ( );                
            currResults [ 2 ] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

            LogDetail ( _testBody, origResult , currResults[0] , 
                        parallelResult , currResults[1], 
                        compositeResults, currResults[2]);

            for ( int l = 0 ; l < currResults.Length ; l++ )
                avgTimes [ l ] = ( ( avgTimes[l]*i)+currResults[l]) 
                                    / ( i + 1 );
        }
        LogDetail ( "\r\nAverage Run Time Original: {0}" , avgTimes[0]);
        LogDetail ( "Average Run Time Parallel: {0}" , avgTimes[1]);
        LogDetail ( "Average Run Time Composite: {0}" , avgTimes [ 2 ] );

        return avgTimes;
    }

    public static double [ ] EqualTill ( string testName, int shortArr1Len , 
                                       int shortArr2Len, int parallelSegLen)
    {

        const string _testHeader = 
               "\r\nTesting When Array Difference is "
               +"Only Length({0}), Array Lengths: {1}, {2}";

        int baseLen = shortArr1Len > shortArr2Len 
                          ? shortArr2Len : shortArr1Len;

        var shortArr1 = new ushort [ shortArr1Len ];
        var shortArr2 = new ushort [ shortArr2Len ];
        double [ ] avgTimes = new double [ 3 ];

        LogDetail( _testHeader , testName , shortArr1Len , shortArr2Len );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {

            FillCompareArray ( shortArr1 , shortArr1Len);
            Array.Copy ( shortArr1 , shortArr2, baseLen );
            double [ ] currElapsedTime = new double [ 3 ];
            var sw = new Stopwatch ( );
            //See previous explaination 
            GC.Collect ( );
            sw.Start ( );
            int origResult = Compare ( shortArr1 , shortArr2 );
            sw.Stop ( );
            currElapsedTime[0] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset ( );

            GC.Collect ( );
            sw.Start ( );
            int parallelResult = CompareParallelOnly ( shortArr1, shortArr2, 
                                     parallelSegLen );
            sw.Stop ( );
            currElapsedTime[1] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset ( );

            GC.Collect ( );
            sw.Start ( );
            var compositeResult = CompareComposite ( shortArr1 , shortArr2 );
            sw.Stop ( );
            currElapsedTime [ 2 ] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

            LogDetail ( _testBody , origResult , currElapsedTime[0] , 
                parallelResult , currElapsedTime[1], 
                compositeResult,currElapsedTime[2]);

            for ( int l = 0 ; l < currElapsedTime.Length ; l++ )
                avgTimes [ l ] = ( ( avgTimes [ l ] * i ) 
                                   + currElapsedTime[l])/(i + 1);
        }
        LogDetail ( "\r\nAverage Run Time Original: {0}" , avgTimes [ 0 ] );
        LogDetail ( "Average Run Time Parallel: {0}" , avgTimes [ 1 ] );
        LogDetail ( "Average Run Time Composite: {0}" , avgTimes [ 2 ] );
        return avgTimes;
    }


    static Random rand = new Random ( );
    public static void FillCompareArray ( ushort[] compareArray, int length ) 
    {
        var retVals = new byte[length];
        ( rand ).NextBytes ( retVals );
        Array.Copy ( retVals , compareArray , length);
    }

    public static int CompareParallelOnly ( ushort [ ] x , ushort[] y, 
                                            int segLen ) 
    {
       int len = x.Length<y.Length ? x.Length:y.Length;
       int compareArrLen = (len/segLen)+1;
       int[] compareArr = new int [ compareArrLen ];
       Parallel.For ( 0 , compareArrLen , 
           new Action<int , ParallelLoopState> ( ( i , state ) =>
       {
           if ( state.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue 
                    && state.LowestBreakIteration.Value < i )
               return;
           int segEnd = ( i + 1 ) * segLen;
           int k = len<segEnd?len:segEnd;

           for ( int j = i * segLen ; j < k ; j++ )
               if ( x [ j ] != y [ j ] )
               {
                   compareArr [ i ] = ( x [ j ].CompareTo ( y [ j ] ) );
                   state.Break ( );
                   return;
               }
       } ) );
       int r=compareArrLen-1;
       while ( r >= 0 ) 
       {
           if ( compareArr [ r ] != 0 )
               return compareArr [ r ];
           r--;
       }
       return x.Length.CompareTo ( y.Length );
    }

    public static int Compare ( ushort [ ] x , ushort [ ] y )
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int len = Math.Min ( x.Length , y.Length );
        while ( pos < len && x [ pos ] == y [ pos ] )
            pos++;

        return pos < len ?
            x [ pos ].CompareTo ( y [ pos ] ) :
            x.Length.CompareTo ( y.Length );

    }

    public static int CompareParallel ( ushort[] x, ushort[] y, int len, 
                                        int segLen )
    {
        int compareArrLen = ( len / segLen ) + 1;
        int [ ] compareArr = new int [ compareArrLen ];
        Parallel.For ( 0 , compareArrLen , 
            new Action<int , ParallelLoopState> ( ( i , state ) =>
        {
            if ( state.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue 
                 && state.LowestBreakIteration.Value < i )
                return;
            int segEnd = ( i + 1 ) * segLen;
            int k = len < segEnd ? len : segEnd;
            for ( int j = i * segLen ; j < k ; j++ )
                if ( x [ j ] != y [ j ] )
                {
                    compareArr [ i ] = ( x [ j ].CompareTo ( y [ j ] ) );
                    state.Break ( );
                    return;
                }
        } ) );
        int r = compareArrLen - 1;
        while ( r >= 0 )
        {
            if ( compareArr [ r ] != 0 )
                return compareArr [ r ];
            r--;
        }
        return x.Length.CompareTo ( y.Length );
    }

    public static int CompareSequential(ushort [ ] x , ushort [ ] y, int len)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        while ( pos < len && x [ pos ] == y [ pos ] )
            pos++;

        return pos < len ?
            x [ pos ].CompareTo ( y [ pos ] ) :
            x.Length.CompareTo ( y.Length );

    }

    public static int CompareComposite ( ushort [ ] x , ushort [ ] y ) 
    {
        const int cutOff = 4096;
        int len = x.Length < y.Length ? x.Length : y.Length;

        if ( len > cutOff && x [ len - 1 ] == y [ len - 1 ]
                 && x [ len/2 ] == y [ len/2 ] )
            return CompareParallel ( x , y , len , (len / 100)*8 );

        return CompareSequential ( x , y, len );
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

Make sure you build with optimized code, the results were very different when I did not include this step, it made the parallel code seem like a much larger improvement then it actually was.

The results I got were around 33% decrease in execution time for very long sets of equal numbers. It still grows linearly with increase of input, but at a slower rate. It also starts off slower for small data sets (less then 4092 on my machine), but usually the amount of time taken was small enough (.001 ms on my machine), that it would be worthwhile to use it in case you do get a large almost equal array.

Comment: "I am doing lots of comparisons of relatively small arrays. These arrays represent the path to a node in an HTML document; the number of elements is the depth of a node, so it's not especially likely it will be more than 30 or 40 for the most part." (see comments to OP). Anyway, you've done a great job, Charles!

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's probably the most generally applicable, though none of them really did much for my very specific use case other than @Romoku's comment "get rid of Math.min". Anyone reading this, though, would be well advised to look at all the answers, there's lots of insight here.

Answer (score 1):

Probably won't make a big difference, but you could set the last element to be different to get rid of the `pos < len` check in the while loop. And the rather trivial `pos++` to `++pos`.

```
public int Compare(ushort[] x, ushort[] y)
{
    int pos = 0;
    int len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);

    // the below is probably not worth it for less than 5 (or so) elements,
    //   so just do the old way
    if (len < 5)
    {
      while (pos < len && x[pos] == y[pos])
        ++pos;

      return pos < len ?
        x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
        x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
    }

    ushort lastX = x[len-1];
    bool lastSame = true;
    if (x[len-1] == y[len-1])
        --x[len-1]; // can be anything else
    else
        lastSame = false;

    while (x[pos] == y[pos])
        ++pos;

    return pos < len-1 ?
        x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
        lastSame ? x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
                 : lastX.CompareTo(y[len-1]);
}
```

**EDIT:** You'll only really get a performance gain where many elements from the start are the same (and it'll be worse when there is an early difference, as pkuderov mentioned).

Comment: seems legit! since some worse perfomance in cases where first couples of items are different(early loop break), but i think it's worth it

Comment: Interesting. Because the arrays represent paths in a tree (which I should have mentioned before), in fact most of the elements will match frequently when the arrays are the same length. I am going to try this..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for a long answer, but the question made me so interested I spent a couple of hours investigating and I want to share results.
I've wrote some test cases generator and rough performance tester

What's there:

1. Generate completely random arrays
2. Check execution times of 3 methods of comparision
3. Generate arrays with high probability of similarity
4. Check execution times.

I was using 3 methods

1. OP's
2. My - Idea - change two indexing operations to pointer increments
3. Dukeling's - Idea - remove unneeded comparision

I Started with short arrays (lenght of 5-15)

method 1 was the fastest on both test variations (it was predicted by pkuderov)

If we increase the length of arrays situation changes.

This i got when array lenght is between 500 and 1500

```
Generating test cases ...
Done. (5258 milliseconds)
Compare1 took 18 milliseconds
Compare2 took 18 milliseconds
Compare3 took 33 milliseconds
Generating 'similar' test cases ...
Done. (5081 milliseconds)
Compare1 took 359 milliseconds
Compare2 took 313 milliseconds
Compare3 took 295 milliseconds
```

So we have slight gain of method 2 compare to 1 and even slighter gain of method 3 in compare to 2;

**Resolution:**

**1. If your arrays are short enough and/or there is high probability of
    diference starting on small index values - there's not much you can
    do (with the methods suggested)

 2. Otherwise you can try some
        combination of methods 2 and 3.**

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleExamples
    {
        class ArrayComparePerformance
        {
            static readonly int testArraysNum = 100000;
            static readonly int maxArrayLen = 1500;
            static readonly int minArrayLen = 500;
            static readonly int maxValue = 10;

            public static void RunTest()
            {
                //Generate random arrays;
                ushort[][] a = new ushort[testArraysNum][];
                ushort[][] b = new ushort[testArraysNum][];

                Random rand = new Random();

                Console.WriteLine("Generating test cases ... " );

                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();

                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int len = rand.Next(maxArrayLen) + 1;
                    a[i] = new ushort[len];
                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                    {
                        a[i][j] = (ushort) rand.Next(maxValue);
                    }



                    len = rand.Next(maxArrayLen) + 1;
                    b[i] = new ushort[len];
                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                    {
                        b[i][j] = (ushort) rand.Next(maxValue);
                    }



                }

                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Done. ({0} milliseconds)", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


                //compare1
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int result = Compare1(a[i], b[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Compare1 took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");

                //compare2
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int result = Compare2(a[i], b[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Compare2 took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");

                //compare3
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int result = Compare3(a[i], b[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Compare3 took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");


                //Generate "similar" arrays;

                Console.WriteLine("Generating 'similar' test cases ... ");

                sw.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int len = rand.Next(maxArrayLen - minArrayLen) + minArrayLen -1;
                    a[i] = new ushort[len];
                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                    {
                        if (j < len/2)
                            a[i][j] = (ushort)j;
                        else
                            a[i][j] = (ushort)(rand.Next(2)  + j);
                    }



                    len = rand.Next(maxArrayLen - minArrayLen) + minArrayLen - 1;
                    b[i] = new ushort[len];
                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                    {
                        if (j < len/2)
                            b[i][j] = (ushort)j;
                        else
                            b[i][j] = (ushort)(rand.Next(2)  + j);
                    }
                }

                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Done. ({0} milliseconds)", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


                //compare1
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int result = Compare1(a[i], b[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Compare1 took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");

                //compare2
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int result = Compare2(a[i], b[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Compare2 took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");

                //compare3
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < testArraysNum; i++)
                {
                    int result = Compare3(a[i], b[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Compare3 took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " milliseconds");


                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public static int Compare1(ushort[] x, ushort[] y)
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
                while (pos < len && x[pos] == y[pos])
                    pos++;

                return pos < len ?
                    x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
                    x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
            }

            public unsafe static int Compare2(ushort[] x, ushort[] y)
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
                fixed (ushort* fpx = &x[0], fpy = &y[0])
                {
                    ushort* px = fpx;
                    ushort* py = fpy;
                    while (pos < len && *px == *py)
                    {
                        px++;
                        py++;
                        pos++;
                    }
                }

                return pos < len ?
                    x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
                    x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
            }

            public static int Compare3(ushort[] x, ushort[] y)
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int len = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);

                // the below is probably not worth it for less than 5 (or so) elements,
                //   so just do the old way
                if (len < 5)
                {
                    while (pos < len && x[pos] == y[pos])
                        ++pos;

                    return pos < len ?
                      x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
                      x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
                }

                ushort lastX = x[len - 1];
                bool lastSame = true;
                if (x[len - 1] == y[len - 1])
                    --x[len - 1]; // can be anything else
                else
                    lastSame = false;

                while (x[pos] == y[pos])
                    ++pos;

                return pos < len - 1 ?
                    x[pos].CompareTo(y[pos]) :
                    lastSame ? x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
                             : lastX.CompareTo(y[len - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great. The major problem with Method 3, removing the comparison, is that it is destructive; I have to set it back afterwards and it would cause thread safety issues. So that may not be an option. Interestingly so far the thing that made the biggest difference is getting rid off `Math.Min` as the 1st commenter suggested.. going to try your pointer suggestion. I even tried using memcmp to compare just the equal-length parts but that actually slowed things down, I think the overhead for short arrays of marshalling not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas (may be wrong, need test):

**First.** The larger items type(e.g. `int` for x32 or `long` for x64 - let's name this type `TLong`) may provide some better perfomance. 
If you pack multiple `ushort` items in type `TLong` item (in [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order!), you'll be able to compare multiple items at once. 
But you'll be needed to take care of the last item of new array [of type `TLong`] if it isn't fullfilled. There may be some 'tricky cases'. I don't see any for now but I'm not sure.
**Second.** Even more! In some cases we can pack more origin items in item of type `TLong`. 
Let's turn back to initial arrays of type `ushort`: let's assume that `K` - the biggest number existed in all(i.e. all paths you want to sort!) of your arrays (i.e. for every number `t` stored in every `ushort` truly: `t <= K`). Let's then imagine that every `t` is just a "digit" in base-`K` numeric system. 
It means that every path in your graph (i.e. every `ushort` array) determines just a number in this numeric system. So instead of manipulate `ushort` arrays you need do smth like this:

1. Determine what the biggest power of `K` fit into type `TLong` - let's assume it's `p`:

   ```
   int p = 0;
   while (Math.Exp(K, p) <= TLong.MaxValue)
       p++;
   ```
2. Take the i-th `p` items of `ushort` array and calculate appropriate number in base-`K`numeric system and keep it as i-th item of type `TLong` array:

   ```
   List<TLong> num = new List<TLong>();
   int i = 0;
   while (p * i < a.Length)
   {
       TLong y = 0;

       //transform from base-10 to base-K in chunks of p elements
       for (int j = p * i; j < Math.Min(p * (i + 1), a.Length); j++)
           y = y * K + a[j];

       num.Add(sum);
       i++;
   }
   TLong[] result = num.ToArray();
   ```
3. This's a dynamic precalculated transformation so for different HTML documents `K` may be different and for case where `K` much less than 255 it will faster than first idea. Also the precalculated transform has linear complexity so it won't greatly affect your perfomance.
4. Generally you transform your arrays into big numbers in base-`K` num. sys. stored in array. That's it!
5. And no need to change the initial sort algorithm with improvements from other comments (check it anyway - I may be wrong!)

I hope it'll help you.