# Efficient data structure for searching "is in string" from a large set of strings

Tags: string, algorithm, search, autocomplete, trie

We all know Google autocomplete.  Type "an" and get possible results beginning with "an", such as "animal."  You could conceive how a prefix-tree (trie) would work well for this.

But what if you wanted to match on "is in string" instead "starts with."  A trie becomes inefficient.

A terrible solution would be:

- Obtain all possibilities Loop on possibilities,
- Retain only those where *inStr(possibility, token)==true*

Comment: How about a prefix tree that also stores partial strings? Ex. When you add "lorem" to the tree, also add "orem", "rem", "em", and "m", each of which stores a reference to the full string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655431/data-structure-for-indexed-searches-of-subsets

Answer (score 1):

[Generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree) is what you're looking for.

From Wikipedia:

> It can be built in `O(n)` time and space, and can be used to find all `z` occurrences of a string `P` of length `m` in `O(m+z)` time